# NSCoding and ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nscoding

I'd like to archive my custom objects.  ClassA holds a dictionary whose values are instances of ClassB.

Everything looks good ClassA's initWithCoder, and _dictionary is declared `strong`, but after init returns and I call `callMeAfterInit`, the _dictionary is empty (not null, a valid empty dictionary).

This ought to be simple, but I haven't used archiving much, so maybe I'm missing something basic.  What might cause the dictionary to be emptied after the init returns?

Here's the essential code:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject <NSCoding>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
@end

@implementation ClassA

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

    [encoder encodeObject:self.dictionary forKey:@"dictionary"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _dictionary = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"dictionary"];
        // breakpoint here and I can inspect a good dictionary, full of ClassB values
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)callMeAfterInit {

    NSLog(@"%@", self.dictionary);
    // Log output here shows an empty dictionary (valid, but with 0 pairs)
}

@end


@interface ClassB : NSObject <NSCoding>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *number;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *array;
@end

@implementation ClassB

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

    [encoder encodeObject:self.number forKey:@"number"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.array forKey:@"array"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _number = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"number"];
        _array = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"array"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the code that calls `callMeAfterInit`, so this is a guess.

More likely than not, you aren't talking to the same instance of `ClassA`.   Did you happen to call `[[ClassA alloc] init];` somewhere?

Comment: I'm going to mark this one correct because it helped me find the error.  Unrelated to the question, I found a line that empties the dictionary after init.  There's just one instance, but looking for an extra instance as this answer suggests caused me to find my mistake.  So the actual correct answer is that I'm a moron.  (The archive stuff is new enough to me that I figured it was that).  Thanks for the help!